# how do I change an objects tag when the game closes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an inventory script, and I change the tags of prefabs to check if my inventory already has them stored, but when I exit the game the tags stay as stored. this is a problem because then it doesnt add or instantiate the prefab. here's the code if it helps

```
  public void AddObjInv(GameObject InvObj, int amount)
    {
        
        if (InvObj.tag != "stored")
        {
           GameObject InvObj2 = Instantiate(InvObj, new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1.0f, transform.position.y, 0f), Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
            if (transform.localScale.x == 1)
            {
                InvObj2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
            }
            InvObj2.name = InvObj.name;
            InvObj2.SetActive(false);
            StoredObj.Add(InvObj2);
            ObjAmount.Add(amount);
            InvObj.tag = "stored";
        }
        else
        {
            ObjAmount[StoredObj.IndexOf(InvObj)] += amount;
        }

    }
```

I tried OnApplicationQuit, but it wouldn't change when I stopped testing.

Comment: It's working as intended. You misunderstand the point of Object tags. They are not there to work as dynamic variables or values or to be treated as booleans. They are exactly as the name says: tags. They are a name and names don't change. What you are trying is no different than wanting to change the class name of an object from "Rifle" to "RiflePickup" when it's dropped and "RifleInventory" when it's grabbed. It doesn't work that way. Use variables for what you need, not tags.

Comment: ill do that then.

Comment: If you want to save some stuff you should use PlayerPrefs for that.
You could for example save a list of InventoryItems (OwnClass) which is serializable and write it as a Json into the Playerprefs. If you then restart you load this and decode it.

Comment: @FelixLenz Not really. PlayerPrefs has a different purpose so it's terrible advice. I see a lot of beginners recommending that and even some tutorials doing it. That is **not** what `PlayerPrefs` is for so stop using it that way.